# cannot clean-up WinSxS temp folder

Tags: windows-server-2019

We have a Server 2019 Core which running out of disk space. The temp folder in C:\Windows\WinSxS\Temp\PendingDeletes and Pending Renames has consumed > 100GB...

I have already attempted Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup, but am getting error relating to 'pending operation'. To make matters worse, this server has also been failing Windows updates for months - which could be contributing to why its unable to successfully clear some space in the component store.

I am able to run Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore, which tells me that clean up is recommended.

Are there any suggestions on how i can clean up the WinSxS temp folder?

Comment: So, just to make sure: You did reboot the machine and then try again, right?

Comment: yes, rebooting is another problem.. on every reboot, Windows updates attempts to install, then fails and reverts updates. so every reboot takes approx 30mintues. :/

Comment: That’s not good. When you say the server is running out of disk space, how much exactly is left? If it is very low, can you (temporarily) make some room by moving stuff away or enlarging the _C:_ partition?

Comment: Provide the Windows Update log.

Comment: have you tried clean manager?